# Connecting ArcGIS feature Service with token (authentication)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, feature-service, authentication, token

How connecting a ArcGIS feature service with a authentication/username?
The link looks like this: https://services1.arcgis.com/code/ArcGIS/rest/services?token=rzJ3BnGbFKOyS7vaMeXnD_yuS_DMm4pTV3EOsf
Notice the token.
Trying this, several times,  in QGIS 3.14, I get a failure every time.
Connecting without authentication it isn't a problem.

Comment: Are you passing a username and password in through your connection? Tokens are short lived and can't be passed around. If you're the exact link you've posted, that token is probably past its lifespan an will need to be renewed (re-authenticate)

Comment: In QGIS, the URL of the service connection should not contain a token.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips:
The result is that one has to use the first part of the code, without the token
cfr https://services1.arcgis.com/code/ArcGIS/rest/services?
and then add authentication. (username/password)

The feature service can now be added to the map.